# Custom Delegation not calling its delegate method in objective c

Tags: ios, delegates

Hey Friends I'm facing a problem in implementing custom delegation Let me explain...

1-I have a pickerview and I had make a Custom class of pickerView for Showing MM/YYYY.

2 - I have a Button in Viewcontroller,what I want is to change button title on didselect of pickerView.I'm implementing it like this...

In UImonthPickerClass I'm implementing like thiss..

```
@protocol UIMonthYearPickerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didChangeDate:(NSDate*)newDate;

@end

@interface CustomMonthYearPicker : UIPickerView <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <UIMonthYearPickerDelegate> declareDelegate;
```

and in didSelect I'm doing it like this...

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if (self.declareDelegate) {

    if ([self.declareDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(pickerView:didChangeDate:)]) {

        [self.declareDelegate pickerView:self didChangeDate:self.date];
    }
}
```

}

In ViewController In which i have button I'm doing like this...

```
@interface AddDetailsViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate,UIMonthYearPickerDelegate> {

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomMonthYearPicker *customMonthYear;

}

 - (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

[customMonthYear setDeclareDelegate:self];

}

#pragma CustomMonthYearProtocol 

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didChangeDate:(NSDate *)newDate {

 NSString *buttonStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newDate];

[self.btnSelectYear setTitle:buttonStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

But it is not updating Button Title on didselect....Why..??please help

Comment: Did you tried a break point, the delegate works or just the UI is not updated?

Comment: I had checked all nothign is wrong....Is there any correction in my code

Comment: Do you set the `delegate` and `dataSource` properties (as distinct from your custom `declareDelegate`) for the `CustomMonthYearPicker`?

Comment: It might be out of the question but I think this line is not correct - [customMonthYear setDeclareDelegate:self]; It should either be self.customMonthYear or _customMonthYear. Also keep a breakpoint in this line - if (self.declareDelegate). Print the value and check if it's nil or not.